# touch.locationInView not working as I thought

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

Im trying to make it so my game recognizes when I touch a node in my scene, except when I use the code below, which I thought would do exactly what I wanted, my app does not correctly identify the position of the node.

I clicked around the rest of the screen printing out the name of the node I was touching, and it turns out that my app thinks the nodes are in a different location than they really are (the x value is correct by the y value is very off)

do you see anything that is wrong?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        var TouchlocationEnd = touch.locationInView(self.view!)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(TouchlocationEnd)

        var name = touchedNode.name

        println(name)

        if name == "start"{
            var scene = PlayScene(size: self.view!.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            self.view!.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that _anything_ is "not working correctly". You should start by assuming that _you_ are at fault, not Cocoa.

Comment: I didn't think Cocoa was wrong, I guess I should have used a different title

Comment: It's not about the title of the question, other @Matt. It's about programming - I'm trying to teach you something about how to program. I'm suggesting that your first thought should not be "what's wrong with this thing" but "what am _I_ not _understanding_?" If you think that way, you won't _need_ to ask these sorts of question on Stack Overflow and waste time and bandwidth; you'll read the docs and do some thinking for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodeAtPoint() function, according to Apple's docs, takes "a point in the node’s coordinate system".  But the point you found is the location in the view, which isn't necessarily in the same coordinate system as whatever node you're subclassing here.

In other words, I'm guessing that the coordinate system of "self.view" is different from the coordinate system of "self".  Try something like this (untested):

```
let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode( self )
let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint( touchPoint )
```

Comment: touch.locationInNode(self) instead of touch.locationInView(self.view!) was the problem thanks!     I also determined that with the code I used, the y value was inverted for some reason.  The top of the screen was 0 while normally its the bottom that is 0...strange

Comment: That's because the coordinate systems for UIView's and SpriteKit are different - the "y axis" goes in a different direction.  (Which is why using those convenience functions correctly is such a good idea!)  Glad you got it fixed.